# How to provide translations for items in a ASP.Net custom web control (.ascx)?

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, ascx

How do I go about providing localised text for items in a custom web control? I had thought that I just need to add meta.resourcekey tags to the control items and then  define and fill some resource files called mycontrol.ascx.[lang].resx but that doesn't seem to work.

e.g.

MyControl.ascx

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" meta:resourcekey="Label1" runat="server" Text="Oops!"></asp:Label>
```

MyControl.ascx.de.resx

```
Label1.Text    Donner und Blitzen!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add meta tags.

Have this in your resource file (MyControl.ascx.de.resx) which will be located in App_LocalResources:

Name       Value

---

SomeName   Oops!

Then in your User Control:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" meta:resourcekey="Label1" runat="server">
    <%=GetLocalResourceObject("SomeName") %>
</asp:Label>
```

That helper method is part of the System.Web.UI.TemplateControl namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you could use global resource files for this, here is a [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasham/RESOURCEFILES02132008080733AM/RESOURCEFILES.aspx) that may help